# grabbing parent records in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm, parentid

**what I have done? and what I need?**

I have created two module 1.invoice 2. payment   there is one to many relationship between invoice and payment 
  it means one invoice have many payment.

for calculating payment   I have used  a logic hook in payment module.

now I want invoice_id in payment module to retrive data.

for that I use

```
$invoice = new invoi_invoice();
$invi = $invoice->get_linked_beans('invoi_invoice_t_hotel_payment_1','invoi_invoice');
var_dump($invi);
```

it return

```
array(0){
}
```

and also I used

```
$invoice = new invoi_invoice();
$id=$invoice->retrieve($bean->invoi_invoice_t_hotel_payment_1invoi_invoice_ida);
```

but this also does not give me id of invoice.

i have read lots of blog and tutorial all are  grabing parent record same like me.
but I don1t get id till now.

any help please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got the solution**

for simply getting the parent id use

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

then you got  parent id like this:-

```
$parent_id=$_REQUEST["return_id"];
```